Import specified `batch` with Elasticsearch rails
I'm using the elasticsearch-model and elasticsearch-rails gems, but I couldn't find a method to import a specific batch to Elasticsearch. Since I need to perform some manipulations on that particular batch, I'm looking for a way to pass it like the example below. However, this results in an ArgumentError:
          model.__elasticsearch__.import(
            batch, 
            batch_size: batch_size,
            refresh: true,
          )


Full method reference:

    def import_orders_with_batched_ip_info(model, associations)
      batch_size = (ENV['ELASTICSEARCH_BATCH_SIZE'] || 10).to_i

      model.includes(*associations).find_in_batches(batch_size: batch_size) do |batch|
        # Get IPs for current batch
        ips = batch.map(&:ip).compact.uniq

        # Fetch and store IP info for this batch
        Thread.current[:batch_ip_info] = fetch_ip_info_batch(ips)

        begin
          # Import all records at once
          model.__elasticsearch__.import(
            batch,
            batch_size: batch_size,
            refresh: true,
          ) do |response|
            handle_import_response(response)
          end
        ensure
          Thread.current[:batch_ip_info] = nil
        end
      end
    end


Please include the relevant part of the stack trace in the question
